# Accessing Sub Array in JSON [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, json

```
var categories = [{
    "categories": {
        "data": [{
            "parent_id": 109,
        },
        {
            "parent_id": 0,
        }]
    }
}];
```

Hello, I have the above JSON object I'm trying to access the parent_id in categories with the following:

```
categories.data[i].parent_id !== 0
```

This is using a for loop with `i < categories.length`.
I've google around and im not finding a good answer to this, is there a cleaner way to access the `parent_id` in the JSON?

EDIT: I implemented the suggested solutions with this and it's working 100% with access to the JSON however the Map() is taking them as undefined. Heres what I did:

```
let byParentId = new Map();
    for (let item of sample) {
      for (let data of item.categories.data) {
        if (data.parent_id !== 0) {
          if (!byParentId.has(data.parent_id)) {
            byParentId.set(data.parent_id, item.categories.data);
          } else {
            byParentId.get(data.parent_id).push(item.categories.data);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
for(let item of categories){
    for(let data of item.categories.data){
        console.log(data.parent_id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I liked this solution and I implemented it however the data is undefined going into my Map. I edited the question with it

Answer (score 0):

`categories` is

```json
{
success: true,
categories: {
data: [stuff]
}
}
```

So `categories.data` does not exist.  So, instead, try `categories.categories.data`, then maybe rewrite your JSON structure.

Comment: pheew that was severely overlooked because I was handed the JSON structure this way. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

your categories variable is array so you must start with categories[i].categories.data[i].parent_id

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a clean and elegant way to work with arrays.

*

> array.filter(i => i['categories']).map(i =>
> i['categories'].data[0]).filter(d => d['parent_id'] !== 0).map(m
> => m.parent_id);

- 

array
.filter(i => i['categories'])  // filter categories

.map(i => i['categories'].data[0]) // get first data

.filter(d => d['parent_id'] !== 0) // filter out parent_id with 0

.map(m => m.parent_id); // get desired parent_id

```js
    
var array = [{
    "categories": {
        "data": [{
            "parent_id": 109,
        },
        {
            "parent_id": 0,
        }]
    }
}];

console.log(array.filter(i => i['categories']).map(i => i['categories'].data[0]).filter(d => d['parent_id'] !== 0).map(m => m.parent_id))
```